# Multiple remote libraries with robot framework

Tags: testing, distributed, robotframework

According to the example in the manual of 'Robot Framework', in order to provide keywords from a remote computer one has to instantiate `RobotRemoteServer` with an instance of the class implementing the Keywords

```
RobotRemoteServer(ExampleRemoteLibrary(), *sys.argv[1:])
```

What if I have multiple libraries/classes which I want to be available remotely? Do I have to start a new server for each class?

Is robot framework suitable for automated distributed testing, where multiple computers have to run synchronously in order to test a particular case?

found a related discussion here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/robotframework-users/remote/robotframework-users/StO7L7NbqFI/rrZa6KeAiMIJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't forced to use `RobotRemoteServer`, that's just a simple example provided as a convenience. You can create a single server that can use as many classes as you want. The only real requirement is that your XMLRPC server exposes the methods `get_keyword_names` and `run_keyword`.

This is all documented in the Robot User Guide, in the section titled [Remote Library Interface](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#remote-library-interface).

As for distributed testing, it's possible to have multiple remote servers on different machines, all coordinated by a single robot test. I'm not sure if that's what you're asking about.