# What is the correct way to specify 'WITH NAME' to access multiple robotframework Remote servers from a single test case?

Tags: integration-testing, robotframework

According to the documentation at http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#remote-library-interface it is very straightforward.  So I tried what is described there:

```
*** Settings ***
Library       Remote   http://${ADDRESS}:${PORT}   WITH NAME LinuxHost
Library       Remote    http://${ADDRESS}:${PORT}  WITH NAME WindowsHost

*** Variables ***
${ADDRESS}    127.0.0.1
${PORT}       8270

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    WindowsHost.Start Process  /bin/sleep    60  
    LinuxHost.Start Process    /bin/sleep    60  
    LinuxHost.Run Process      /bin/sleep    20
```

This fails with

```
Error in file 'processtest.txt': Test Library 'Remote' expected 0 to 1 arguments, got 2.
```

I'm running the python remote server like this:

```
from robot.libraries import Process 
r=robotremoteserver.RobotRemoteServer(Process.Process(),'0.0.0.0')
```

When I just have one library without 'WITH NAME' keyword it works fine.  This is robotserver 2.8.5.

This is the opposite question from [Multiple remote libraries with robot framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089187/multiple-remote-libraries-with-robot-framework).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have enough spaces between `WITH NAME` and the name that follows. You need two or more spaces so that `WITH NAME` is in a column by itself.

Robot looks for the literal words `WITH NAME` -- and *only* those words -- within a cell. Since you don't have enough spaces separating it from the next cell, robot thinks this is just another argument to the remote library.

From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> The basic syntax for specifying the new name is having the text WITH NAME (case-insensitive) after the library name **and then having the new name in the next cell**

Comment: Thanks.  I wondered how robotframework was separating tokens (columns) - I'm obviously still in the "quick start" phase.

Comment: @Marvin: if you're just now learning, I recommend using the pipe separated format. See [this blog post](http://boakley.github.io/2014/08/20/why-I-like-pipe-formatted-tests/) for an explanation.

Comment: @Marvin: another option to avoid these kinds of issues is to use RIDE. It handles all the file formatting for you.

Comment: @Bryan I read some more documentation, and I agree that pipe separator is a good approach.  I'm trying to bring this technology into our development group, so clarity is good.  I also came across robot.tidy, which is useful switching between formats to see how they look.