# Robot Framework Remote Server for Robot Keywords

Tags: python, robotframework, keyword, remote-server

I want to implement a [Robot Framework Remote Library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#remote-library-interface) in order to both provide Python classes and Robot Framework Keywords available for multiple clients; this is my idea to aviod copy/paste codes on multiple servers.

I followed instructions described [here](https://github.com/robotframework/PythonRemoteServer/issues) which is trying to implement a server providing Python classes. I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089187/multiple-remote-libraries-with-robot-framework?answertab=active#tab-top) which is implying how I can implement my own server.

But I found nothing while googling around about how to make a server to provide Robot Framework Keywords. Any idea how can I implement such server?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You say you "found nothing while googling around", yet it appears you know where to look in the user guide, which fully explains the process. What part of creating a remote server is unclear? You have both a full description from the user guide, and a sample implementation with PythonRemoteServer.

Comment: @BryanOakley, the documentation and the example explains how to make a remote server for python implemented classes and methods; it doesn't describe how I should implement some for robot implemented keywords. However, I am trying to find a way.

Comment: Oh, ok, you're trying to serve up keywords written in robot? I don't think you can do that.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on your use case; i.e. why you're doing this? "...avoid copy/paste codes on multiple servers .." Doesn't explain why this is problematic for you. Typically we see Remote Libraries setup to allow access to applications/classes written in other programming languages (java, Ruby, Javascript, etc). However, it introduces an additional chain which in itself is undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

Running same tests on several servers doesn't mean you need copy paste code or use remote server. 
 I would Implement tests(robot & python libraries), put them in  git repository, control test runs with Jenkins master & slaves. Slaves would be running on the servers and checking out the tests from repository and publishing results on Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking how to serve up robot keywords written in robot itself, rather than in a programming language.

I don't think it's possible to do what you want. The remote library interface is for keyword *libraries*, and by definition those keyword libraries are written in other programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

That can't be done right now - there is an open enhancement opened for this: https://github.com/robotframework/PythonRemoteServer/issues/42